# checkboxlist is giving result vertically

Tags: yii

I am trying to make a checkboxlist and for the same i have used this statement
`<?php echo CHtml::checkBoxList('interests', '',
array('PHP', 'MySQL', 'JavaScript', 'CSS',
'Yii Framework')); ?>`


But it is giving me the output in which The names (**'PHP', 'MySQL','JavaScript', 'CSS',
'Yii Framework'**) specifying the checkboxes are below the boxes while I **want the names to be with them horizontally**.

Comment: attach the downloadable class to your question please.

Comment: I have defined this statement in the **_form.php**....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way to solve your problem is you can define style for input-checkbox in your checkboxlist like:

```
#interests input {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Your inputs (checkbox) and labels will be horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to customize CSS to do that. Yii has a attribute called "separator" this built in. You can easily get rid of the line breaks by doing this:

```
echo CHtml::checkBoxList('...','...', array(...),
  array(
    'separator'=>'', //the default was a line break...
    )
);
```

Comment: It won't make the input (checkbox) and label are horizontal!

Comment: @jackhao I am afraid to tell you sir that I tried and Secretlm is right...its not working :(

Answer (score 1):

OK - I got it to work. Here's what I used. The separator will remove the spacing between lines, and float achieves the box on the same line as description.

```css
.checkBoxClass
{
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="itemGroups" class="itemGroups">
 <?php echo $form->checkBoxList($model, 'groups', $group_items,  
  array(
   'separator' => '',
   'class'=>'checkBoxClass',
  )
 );?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo CHtml::checkBoxList(
    'interests', 
    '', 
    array('PHP', 'MySQL', 'JavaScript', 'CSS', 'Yii Framework'), 
    array('labelOptions' => 
           array(
                 'style' => "display: inline-block"
           )
    )
);
```

Or better specify some class in your CSS file

```
.mylabelclass {
 display: inline-block
}
```

and use

```
array('labelOptions' => 
       array(
               'class' => "mylabelclass"
       )
)
```